# How to pass variables in header?

Tags: php

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$extra = '/portfolio_ln/thank-you.php';
header("Location: http://$host$extra");
```

I want to redirect my page to `thankyou.php` which is in `portfolio_ln` directory. But it's redirecting me to same page. How to do this? Need help!

Comment: echo out `http://$host$extra` and see what you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), headers must be sent before any output is printed.

Make sure you aren't printing anything before the `header()` function.

This includes whitespaces before `<?php`, and make sure your php file is saved as `UTF8 without BOM`

A possible workaround is to use `ob_start` and `ob_clean` to ignore the output if you want to redirect.

Comment: How can i use "ob_start and ob_clean"?

Comment: the first line code should be `ob_start();`, when you finished printing the page write `ob_end_flush()`, and when you want to redirect use `ob_clean()` before the `headers()` function

Comment: You are great URi. I just have 14 reputation, o/w i would definitely mark you accepted. sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: http://".$host.$extra);
```

Answer (score 1):

from your code it appears you tried to concatenate `$host` & `$extra`   use the below code in the header function:

```
header("Location: http://".$host.$extra);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your PHP variables,

```
header("Location: http://{$host}{$extra}");
```